# How to generate URL to view when using Traversal?

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

When URL Dispatch is used, we can easily generate a URL to a view because every view has a distinct route_name like:

```
login.py:
@view_config(route_name='login')

index.pt:
<a href="${request.route_url('login')}">Login</a>
```

But how to do this in traversal? Since there is no instance of resources 'Login' available, I don't know how to generate URL to view login.

Comment: without knowing anything about your resource tree this is just a guess...  request.resource_url(request.context, "login") or request.resource_url(request.root, "login") but it all depends on how your resourcetree is structured for traversal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In traversal you are required to know the structure of your tree, and you must be able to load context objects on demand. The URLs are generated with respect to a context, using its location-aware properties `__name__` and `__parent__` to build the URL.

```
/
|- login
|- users
   |- 1
      |- edit
```

So let's say we have a `User(id=1)` context object, and we want to login. If your view is registered via `@view_config(context=Root, name='login')`, then you can generate the url via `request.resource_url(request.root, 'login')`. This is us telling Pyramid to generate a URL relative to the root of the tree.

On the other hand, if we are at login and we want to take the user to edit you must load a location-aware `User` object for that user in order to generate the URL. `request.resource_url(user, 'edit')` where `user` is an instance of `User(id=1)` with valid `__name__` and `__parent__` attributes.

If you pass in a context without a location-aware `__parent__` the URL will be generated as if your user was mounted at `/` because that's the only sane place for Pyramid to think the object would be in your tree.

The ability to load a location-aware object is why we stress that traversal works best with a **persistent** tree of objects, not one that is generated on the fly. It's much more convenient to directly load the user and have its `__parent__` and `__name__` already populated for you if you want to generate URLs for it.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! But what about hybrid application which mixed URL dispatch and Traversal? How do I generate URL for that kind of application? I believe there are multiple Roots for a hybrid application because we can mount a traversal resource tree to several point via URL dispatch. How to get the root object for a selected tree? Or my idea is completely wrong? Thanks!

Comment: There is not good support for generating urls within a hybrid application. The general idea is to use `request.resource_path()` or `pyramid.traversal.resource_path()` to generate a relative path and then concatenate that to the result of `request.route_url()`. Another option is to use `request.route_url('foo', traverse=path)` where path is a tuple of segments possibly retrieved via `pyramid.traversal.resource_path_tuple()`. It's not so pretty. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[resource_url](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.resource_url)(resource, 'view_name')

Comment: Do you mind telling me what the first parameter is? If it is a instance of a resource, how can I get it? In the above login example, how can I obtain the instance of login in template? Thanks

Comment: It is resource on which you registered your 'login' view. Assuming it is Auth resource under Root with name 'auth'. Than req.resource_url(req.root['auth'],'login')