# SQLAlchemy and Traversal: How to add traversal required attributes for objects retrived from database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, traversal

I have a resource tree structure like this:

```
Root
|
|
\-- Article
|     |
|     \-- 1
|     \-- 2
|
\-- User
      |
      \-- 1
      \-- 2
```

When user access "/Article", I will show a list of all article:

```
@view_config(context='resource.ArticleDispatcher', renderer='nothing-related')
def article_list(context, resource):
    articles = request.db.query(Article)
    return {'articles': articles}
```

But in the template, I found I have no way to invoke 'req.resource_url(ARTICLE_OBJECT)' because the object 'articles' I retrieved from database has neither **name** nor **parent** set.

Now I don't know how to generate URL in such a situation... :-( Is my design incorrect?

Comment: This question is what I was trying to avoid in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15093393/704327 by explaining how things fall apart if you do not have a **persistent** tree.

Comment: Thanks for [Michael's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15093393/704327). I'm sorry I haven't notice your last paragraph.

Comment: Regardless of whether `articles` is list of SA objects or just dictionaries of serialized values (I prefer this), you should be able to use `req.resource_url(req.context, str(article.id))` to get the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have your Article objects properly inserted into the traversal tree automatically, the most direct way is to access them via the parent's `__getitem__` method, which would work just fine if you were accessing an individual article: `/Articles/123`

When you're displaying a listing, you're not really traversing to individual articles, it's just a coincidence that you want to display a list of articles at `/Articles`, so this case is not covered directly by traversal (which is about *traversing a URI*). There are a few quick fixes to make it look like it is traversal though:

```
@view_config(context='resource.ArticleDispatcher')
def article_list(context, request):
    all_articles_ids = context.magically_get_ids_of_all_articles()
    articles = [context[id] for id in all_articles_ids]
    return {'articles': articles}
```

here you somehow know all ids of all articles you need and just get the children via the traversal one by one which inserts them into traversal context. In many situations (especially with an SQL backend) this won't be very efficient though because you'll need to issue a separate query for each object.

Second, more realistic example: manually insert articles into traversal context:

```
@view_config(context='resource.ArticleDispatcher')
def article_list(context, request):
    articles = context.adopt_children(request.db.query(Article))
    return {'articles': articles}

class ArticleDispatcher(object):
    def adopt_children(self, children):
        for child in children:
            child.__name__ = child.id # actually I'd made __name__ a property of the Article model
            child.__parent__ = self
        return children
```

Third example: do not bother with pretending you're traversing to articles and just do something like

```
req.resource_url(ARTICLE_DISPATCHER) + '/' + article.id
```

in this case you may not even need to query for full Article objects, you may only query for name and id (which in some situations may be faster):

```
@view_config(context='resource.ArticleDispatcher')
def article_list(context, resource):
    name_id_tuples = request.db.query(Article.id, Article.name).all()
    return {'articles': name_id_tuples}
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! That's a great way to get this kind of problem solved. I never though of adding a method in my resource tree to fill the traversal attributes :-)